# rsync on NTFS - permissions

Tags: linux, backup, permissions, ntfs, rsync

I'm backing up directories on a Fedora machine onto an NTFS drive (`fuseblk` according to `df -T`) and it seems to go just fine with this:

```
ls -t | sed -e "1,"$n"d" | xargs -d '\n' rm -rf

nice rsync -azv \
--link-dest=$DestDir/current \
--delete \
--delete-excluded \
$SrcDirs $DestDir/incomplete_backup-$Date

mv $DestDir/incomplete-backup-$Data $DestDir/Backup-$Date
rm -f $DesDir/current
ln -s $DestDir/Backup-$Data $DestDir/current
```

This gives me nice rolling backups and I can limit how many historical versions I have with the `n` variable.

What I notice is that if I execute the backup twice within a few seconds, I get a very long list of modified files.  Exploring further with the `-i` switch, I see that all the files are flagged as having permissions changes.  If I specify `--no-perms`, this fixes the problem.  Assuming it is actually a problem.

My questions are:  Why are permissions not being preserved?  Does this situation negate my rolling backup concept?  Any other details I should be considering?

Comment: Are you sure that `--link-dest` even works on NTFS?  Perhaps it has been updated, but last time I looked the fuse driver didn't support hardlinks for ntfs.

Comment: @Zoerdache - excellent question and clearly of interest.  I may simply reformat to ext4 as tink suggested below, but I would be interested to know the answer to hardlinks on NTFS.

Comment: Hmmm.  I've been going from HFS+ to NTFS with similar behavior.  But in my case, it is updating all NTFS directories every time, but files, only the ones it should be.  http://superuser.com/questions/1111844/why-does-rsync-update-ntfs-directories-when-the-source-has-not-changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the permission are not preserved.  NTFS has no knowledge of Linux ownerships and permissions.

Comment: Instead of NTFS, copy the files to some Linux compatible file system, e.g. ext3 or ext4, and the permissions will be copied over.

Comment: And this is why rsync keeps trying to set the permissions on every backup, correct?  No files are copied, but it tries to modify permissions?

Comment: Correct.  If you want to avoid that format the NTFS device w/ ext2/3/4 (jfs, xfs, reiser, ... anything Linux native) :)